# xev does not respond to numeric keypad keys

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, mouse

xev gives no response for my "/", "*", and "-" keys!!
but outputs those responses below for "0", "+", and "." on my numpad keys,

ButtonPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x7000001,
root 0x29f, subw 0x7000002, time 7612621, (41,34), root:(902,488),
state 0x200, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x7000001,
root 0x29f, subw 0x7000002, time 7614367, (41,34), root:(902,488),
state 0x300, button 1, same_screen YES

how can I find the keycode for all my numpad keys includes "/", "*", "-", "0", "+", and "." keys???
Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [Mouse Keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension#Mouse_control) enabled. When Mouse Keys is enabled, the keypad keys 1 through 9 except 5 make the mouse cursor move in the corresponding direction, and the other keypad keys simulate button actions. Since pressing the key sends a mouse event rather than a keyboard event, xev shows you a mouse event.

Mouse Keys can be toggled by pressing a key that depends on your keyboard configuration. The key is whatever is bound to `Pointer_EnableKeys`, which is usually <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd>. [This used to be enabled by default](https://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/xkb-mouse-emulation-removed-from.html), but nowadays the feature is off by default, and only enabled if `keypad:pointerkeys` is listed in `XKBOPTIONS`.

Comment: Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' thank you. Shift+NumLock works! now xev can detect my mouse key buttons!